# How to format/beautify rails erb code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to format/beautify rails erb code. The view code is a mix of erb and JS.

I tried using the following tool as well, but it didn't help
https://github.com/katgironpe/rails-erb-lint

Comment: what editor you do use ?

Comment: Are we talking about formatting code on your screen, like an editor or IDE. Or a tool as part of a build / Continues Integration environment?

Comment: editor or IDE and not CI

Answer (score 3):

A good IDE to format/beautify rails is **[RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/)**.

**RubyMine** is able to reformat many types of files, like *Ruby*, *HTML*,  *JavaScript*, *CSS*, etc.

example for reformat erb file:

Before: 
[image: Before formatting code]

After:
[image: After formatting code]

You can set the code style in the **Preferences / Editor / Code Style**

Comment: I second this. I've used PHPStorm for years so when I moved over to Ruby, I bought a subscription for RubyMine. I've enjoyed it so far.

Answer (score 2):

The tool which you already used, i.e., rails-erb-lint, checks only for the validity of you ERB and doesn't help with beautifying the ERB code. I don't know which editor you are using, but you can try either [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) or [Github's Atom](https://atom.io/). Both of these have 3rd party packages to beautify Ruby and ERB code. Moreover, the indentation and trailing whitespace removing ability of these editors are enough to beautify/format the ERB files, though they have menu items/ shortcuts to do this on-demand/selectively too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sublime Text, check out this "**Sublime Text 2 & 3 Plugin to [BeautifyRuby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby)**":

**https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby**

Once installed via Sublime's Package Control System you can use the shortcut **`ctrl + alt + k`** (on Windows + Linux) or  **`ctrl + cmd + k`** (on OS X) to beautify your Ruby and erb-files manually - or configure the plugin to do that automatically before saving any Ruby- and erb-file. Configuration is easy - you find the config-file here (via the Sublime- menu):

**`Preferences > Package Settings > BeautifyRuby > Settings - Default`**:

```js
{
    // Specify your ruby interpreter (below). (Note, if you are using a linux distro with Rbenv instead of RVM, then try the following path: "ruby": "~/.rbenv/shims/ruby")  
    "ruby": "~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", 
    // Use 2 Spaces instead of tabs: 
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "tab_size": 2,
    // You can change the file patterns handled by this plugin:
    "file_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb", "\\.rb", "\\.rake", "Rakefile", "Gemfile", "Vagrantfile"],
    "html_erb_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb"],
    // This package offers a pre-save hook; when activated, your ruby and erb files will 
    // be reformatted automatically before saving (deactivated by default)
    "run_on_save": false,
    // The sublime command "beautify_ruby" performs a save after formatting. 
    // (activated by default) 
    "save_on_beautify": false    
}
```

BeautifyRuby depends on the Ruby gem [htmlbeautifier](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier), which needs to be installed on your system first. Otherwise the plugin throws an error each time you try to beautify your code. Make sure, the ruby-interpreter-setting in the config file shown above points to the correct ruby which holds the htmlbeautifier-gem...